# React App not install,show error abortion installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

- node --version => 14.5.0
- npm --version => 6.14.6
- create-react-app --version => 3.4.1
- yarn --version => 1.22.4

I tried all ways to solve this problem but all in vain. I reinstall node update every thing also consult stackoverflow but i am unable to solve this....please help me....

[image]

Comment: Please add detailed error logs. might be a permission issue

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

If you, by any luck visited the create-react-app GitHub repository.
You could have found that the create-react-app as a package is not deprecated, and thus you have to use the npx thing over here.

create-react-app officially asks you to uninstall create-react-app and use the npx script.

First, uninstall create-react-app

```sh
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

And then simple run the following command to create a new react-app

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Then you can change directory to my-app and run it using npm.

```
cd my-app
npm start
```

Comment: @MuhammadHusnain ok, I understand, can you give us more information like npm version, 
and as you can see the error is EPERM: Operation not permitted.